# Help with C Program Executable - Linux

Tags: c, linux, compilation, codeblocks

I just recently made the move to Linux, and now looking to program on it as well.

However, for some reason I cannot get an executable to work.

Here's what I've done:

1. Downloaded Code::Blocks
2. Made a new Console Project in Workspace 1 with C source.
3. Added a `getchar()` before `return(0);`
4. Ran and Compiled - Which works perfectly INSIDE Code::Blocks
5. Went to the bin/release folder in which the file is saved, tried double clicking, right clicking and selecting: open, open with, tried using terminal to run the name of my program. I copied the folder URL, and then name of the file.. I just can't seem to get the created file to execute!

In windows it made a .exe, I know there is no ending (?) in linux.  (Could be wrong).

I'm currently running Ubuntu 11.04.

Comment: I think that debugging this issue would be more suited to the chat rooms. There is no actual question here.

Comment: What error message do you get when you open the program from your terminal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most Linux distributions don't include the current directory in the PATH variable that determines where to search for executables.  Try opening a terminal, changing to the bin/release directory and explicitly qualifying your executable for the current directory:

```
./myprogram
```

This is in contrast to Windows, where you can simply type "myprogram.exe".

Answer (score 2):

You might need to grant your program permission to run as an executable:

```
sudo chmod +x yourProgram
```

Answer (score 0):

In the terminal emulator, go to (cd) the folder where the executable is created.

Type `./programname`

Where programname is the name of the executable file
(./ tells the shell to look in the current directory for the program to run)